# VirtualBox networking question

Tags: virtualbox, virtualhost

I'm running a dev server on a VirtualBox installation running Windows Server 2003. I'd like to access the virtual machine from my host machine's browser (i.e http://virtualhost/) - anyone know how I can set this up?

Answer (score 2):

Broadly, you have a couple of options:

1. Configure the virtual machine to use **bridged** networking. This will essentially put the VM onto the same LAN as your host, so you should provide for its IP configuration either via your LAN's DHCP server, or a static assignment.
2. Configure the virtual machine to use the **host-only** network. This will put the VM onto a virtual LAN that exists ONLY inside the host machine. For convenience, VirtualBox provides a built-in DHCP server on the host-only network, but you are also free to configure your host-only virtual NICs statically, of course.

The only remaining hitch is getting the 'virtualhost' name to resolve to the correct IP address, so that http://virtualhost/ will function as you expect. If you statically configured your VM's NIC, then you can put it into your host's `hosts` file (at `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`). Otherwise, you'll have to figure out a way to dynamically update your DNS with your VM's IP.

Comment: The name isn't important, an IP address would work just as well - I tried connecting to the local IP on the vurtual machine from my host, but it timed out.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with the details about your virtual network configuration? "It timed out" isn't enough to go on, since that is a symptom of any of a number of misconfigurations.

Comment: It's really simple, I just have one virtual machine running and I want to connect to it from the host machine. I tried connecting to the virtual server's IP from my host after configuring the machine to sue both bridged and host-only networking, but neither one worked.